# Change a text and an icon according to the current date of a time zone

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

How do i change an icon and a text according to the current date?
For example lets say icon A and a text that says this is the first part of the year appears from January first to June 30th. How do I write my code in flutter so the text changes to this is the second part of the year and then the icon changes to icon B when the current date is July to December. Also, I don't want the code to take the current date from the location of the phone. I want to use the current date of the time zone `utc+1`.

Also, I got a flutter package for a clock.
Here is the link [clock package](https://pub.dev/packages/analog_clock).

The documentation of the package is not really that detailed. How do I code the clock so it doesn't show the current time of the phone but the current time of a particular time zone I choose. eg `utc+1`. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the month of the current time adjusted per your requirements and display the correct text/icon. Here is an example of how to handle the text. You would follow the same approach for the icon and any other adjustments you'd want to make.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final now = DateTime.now().toUtc().add(const Duration(hours: 1));
  return Text(
    now.month < 7
        ? 'This is the first half of the year'
        : 'This is the second half of the year',
  );
}
```

Comment: i have no idea on how to edit this line.  final now = DateTime.now().toUtc().add(const Duration(hours: 1)); can you please edit it for me so it shows the current date of utc+1. Also, can you please answer the question about the clock

Comment: That line just gives you a DateTime set to the current time in UTC+1.

Comment: You would pass the same DateTime to your AnalogClock.

Comment: Also. how do i write it if I wanted the text to change between October to December and to change again in all other months

Comment: You can use the `month` field in the DateTime to execute whatever logic you want. Either use the ternary notation I used above, or simple if/else pattern before returning the widget.